# Prevent page caching and avoid redirect

Tags: php, browser-cache

My site is written in PHP, and I use redirects to prevent page caching. That is, when a user opens `page.php?page=info`, he is redirected (302) to `page.php?page=info&timestamp=20151030120000`. But this sometimes gets slow, and besides I am afraid that web crawlers like Google or Yahoo don't like that. SSL is a bit too expensive, and META tags seem to be ineffective at all. What else can be done to prevent caching? Thank you!

Comment: why is meta tags seem to be ineffective??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try it through the meta tags, try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Mon, 03 Jun 2015 00:00:00 GMT"/>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Or directly on the page:

```
<?php

  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!

Comment: Excellent stuff.  Glad to help